# Aggregating query on Table?

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery

I am stuck in one point i have to pick the data from the customer table which has values of customer_id and amount_paid . I want to show a result in the form that first 3 values of the user should be visible in a column name group as a text Group1 and 4 to 10 values of that user to get text Group2 and rest Group3 .

Can you please tell me how to group the values for every customer ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> I want to show a result in the form that first 3 values of the user should be visible in a column name group as a text Group1 and 4 to 10 values of that user to get text Group2 and rest Group3

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  user_id, 
  CASE 
    WHEN pos BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN 1
    WHEN pos BETWEEN 4 AND 10 THEN 2
    ELSE 3
  END grp,
  SUM(amount_paid) amount_paid
FROM (
  SELECT 
    user_id, amount_paid, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY amount_paid DESC) pos
  FROM customer 
)
GROUP BY user_id, grp
-- ORDER BY user_id, grp
```

You can test / play with below dummy generated data

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH users AS (
  SELECT user_id FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1,5)) user_id
),
amounts AS (
  SELECT ROUND(50 * RAND()) amount_paid FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1,50)) amount_paid
),
customer AS (
  SELECT user_id, ROUND(amount_paid * RAND()) amount_paid  
  FROM users
  CROSS JOIN amounts
)
SELECT
  user_id, 
  CASE 
    WHEN pos BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN 1
    WHEN pos BETWEEN 4 AND 10 THEN 2
    ELSE 3
  END grp,
  SUM(amount_paid) amount_paid
FROM (
  SELECT 
    user_id, amount_paid, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY amount_paid DESC) pos
  FROM customer 
)
GROUP BY user_id, grp
ORDER BY user_id, grp
```

The output will look like below

```sql
user_id grp amount_paid  
1       1   147.0    
1       2   323.0    
1       3   879.0    
2       1   147.0    
2       2   323.0    
2       3   879.0    
 . . .
```

so you still need calculate share which (from your question and hopefully) is not a problem for you

> added share calculation

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH grps AS (
  SELECT
    user_id, 
    CASE 
      WHEN pos BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN 1
      WHEN pos BETWEEN 4 AND 10 THEN 2
      ELSE 3
    END grp,
    SUM(amount_paid) amount_paid
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      user_id, amount_paid, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY amount_paid DESC) pos
    FROM customer 
  )
  GROUP BY user_id, grp
)
SELECT * ,
  ROUND(amount_paid / SUM(amount_paid) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id), 3) share
FROM grps
-- ORDER BY user_id, grp
```

Comment: Thanks alot Mikhail :)

Comment: nested query would be fine - i don't see a necessity of having all in one run. it is of course sexy but more prune to errors and hard to maintain. feel good about nested query - just try and let us know if still help with this will be needed :o)

Comment: Hi Mikhail, I tried but I am not getting success . Would you guide how could I solve this?

Comment: can you be more specific about your issue. what exactly does not work for you?

Comment: Thanks Mikhail for help. I will gain more knowledge about partition in SQL for future tasks.

Comment: I realized you removed bigquery tag which makes my answer nonsense even though I spent sometime on it and helping you. please do not remove it then. I understand  - you suddenly changed your mind and decided to go with mysql on this  - which I think now is reflected enough as you removed bigquery from title.